# Running Command on a Router Line By Line (JSCH API)

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I have written a method in Java, which takes an ArrayList of Strings and tries to run the command on a CISCO router console one by one. And I am trying to print the output of each command on the console. I am using the Jsch API for it.

I am able to connect to the router just fine using SSH. But when I print the `OutputStream` to the console it just prints the same thing over and over again. No output of the commands I sent. I intentionally have a few incorrect commands in there so that the console prints the error, but I get no such thing.

Here is my method:

```
/**
 * Deliver a config to the router line by line.
 * @param configLines
 * @throws DeviceExcpetion
 */
public void deliverConfig(List<String> configLines) throws DeviceExcpetion {

    Channel channel = null;
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;

    try {

        session = jSch.getSession(userid, ipAddress, port);

        // Set the password.
        session.setPassword(password);

        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        // Finally make the connection.
        session.connect();

        channel = session.openChannel("shell");

        InputStream inputStream = null;

        ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        channel.setOutputStream(responseStream);

        channel.connect();

        for (String line : configLines) {

            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(line.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            channel.setInputStream(inputStream);

            if (channel.isConnected()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            String responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());

            System.out.println(responseString);
        }

    } catch (JSchException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new DeviceExcpetion(e.getMessage());

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        throw new DeviceExcpetion(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }

        if (channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to comment without knowing what 'configLines' are. If they are commands, then it looks like you should have ```channel = session.openChannel("exec");```

Comment: @g00se Yes, they are CISCO router commands.

Comment: I personally would begin by checking that they can be run as a shell script manually (but all together)